# DateString and localization, $Language ignored

Tags: localization

I have a `DateString` calculated in English.

Now I would like to change the output according to localization. I have read that localization is possible for Menu, Messages and Cells. A simple `$Language = "French"` before calling `DateString` is ignored.

Since this should be a basic feature for localization, I am wondering if my keywords for Google and SX are just plain wrong? Or is this feature not present?

Comment: It uses your operating system's language settings, not `$Language`.  Try to change the regional settings of your OS.  This did change the date formatting for me on WIndows

Comment: I actually had a similar problem, which I could work around once known but never got a solution. Here is my [question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/OhtYTtoze3o/_ybGLw09Z1cJ) in mathgroup. There were no answers for that question there, as far as I can see and remember...

Comment: Actually, my OS regional settings are not English. I only installed Mathematica with English interface to be sure to have the same "wording" when discussing with colleagues. Strange. Every high-level language nowadays has this feature (incl. Java). Thus it is just not implemented in pure MM. Ok, there's still the possibility to make a Java call...

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: Win7 64bit with MM9

Answer (score 6):

Ok, There seems to be some agreement, that the function is not natively implemented in MM. Thus, I will try to answer my question with a workaround. My answer is based on [a java question over at SX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string)

```
In[1]:= Needs["JLink`"]
        InstallJava[];
        LoadJavaClass["java.text.DateFormat"];
        LoadJavaClass["java.util.Date"];
        LoadJavaClass["java.util.Locale"];
In[2]:= date = JavaNew["java.util.Date"];

In[3]:= df = DateFormat`getDateInstance[DateFormat`LONG, Locale`GERMANY];
        df@format[date]

Out[3]= "19. März 2013"

In[4]:= df = DateFormat`getDateInstance[DateFormat`LONG, Locale`FRANCE];
        df@format[date]
Out[4]= "19 mars 2013"

In[5]:= df = DateFormat`getDateInstance[DateFormat`LONG, Locale`ITALY];
        df@format[date]
Out[5]= "19 marzo 2013"
```

Maybe someone can come up with a better solution. Since then, I stay with my opinion that this feature is basic and should be implemented in MM before any (ugly) tachometer or so onis added to the UI - At least I don't want a Labview like MM...